# Redirect/open a tab of another page in my website after a google sheet change

Tags: javascript, web, url, google-sheets

After a visitor finishes to fill a questionnaire on my website, a google sheet is updated. I want that for each update/change that is made in that google sheet that visitor will be redirected to another page in my website (or that page will open in a new tab), according to the changes made to that google sheet (in a specific cell, A1).

My code opens a new tab with the URL that is in cell A1 in that google sheet, but only after I directly make a change in that google sheet. The problem is that If I make the changes by filling the questionnaire in my website (or for that matter through changing another google sheet that is linked to that sheet), nothing happens. How can I change it? In other words, **how can I trigger my code so that for every change** in A1, that is caused from filling the questionnaire in my website, a window will be open (or the visitor will be redirected to that page)?

```
 function myFunction() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
 var numRows = 5; // Number of rows to process
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 url1 = data[0];// first column
 var js = '<script>'+
'window.open("'+url1+'".replace(/,/g, ""),"_blank", "width=800, height=600");' +
'google.script.host.close();</script>'
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
.setHeight(10)
.setWidth(100);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.');   
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `The problem is that If I make the changes by filling the questionnaire in my website (or for that matter through changing another google sheet that is linked to that sheet), nothing happens.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and goal? I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: The questionnaire in my website is linked to a google sheet, which makes calculatons and changes according to what the respondent answers on the questionnaire. For each change in the google sheet, I triggered the google sheet to open a new tab with a url that is in its cell A1. The problem is that the new tab won't open after filling the questionnaire, despite that the google sheet changes. Meaning, changing the google sheet by filling the questionnaire on my website does not open the new tab. Only when I change directly values ​​in the google sheet itself the tab opens..

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your situation. But when I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question. But you have a personal website that you would like to redirect based on a value of a google spreadsheet? How have you linked your spreadsheet to your website? You can not redirect from Apps Script if you are on your website. This seems like a full javascript job on your side.